# javascript to display "Are you sure you want to navigate from this page" in a consistent manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have a requirement to display a warning message ("Are you sure you want to navigate from this page" ) when a user tries navigates off from a page.
I got this working using the: window.beforeunload event.

```
var warning = true;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (event) {
   if ((warning)) {
        return "You will lose your unsaved changes";
   }
 });
```

The issue I'm running into is, I've a couple of links in this page that results in ajax calls- which would not result in  the 'window.beforeunload' getting triggered. 
Question is: How do I display the message in the same exact manner when we click on these links. I did try the using the "confirm" dialog - it works but the message appears in the dialog window and not in the native browser like it would in the first case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between dialog window and native browser

Comment: You cannot do this _completely_ consistently.

Comment: The `confirm` dialog is actually the native dialog window.
What are you using to display the warning?

Comment: Like On IE 8 (yeah I'm still stuck with IE 8), the confirm dialog would display the message in a "window" titled -"Message from web-page" with my message and the OK and Cancel buttons. But when the js on 'beforeunload' is triggered, I get a completly different window-to me its the actual IE window- titled -Windows Internet Explorer. I also see "Are you sure you want to navigate from this page message" above my custom "You will lose your unsaved changes" message. The icon displayed is also different b/w the confirm dialog and this

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var warning = true;

    var showWarning = function (event) {
       if ((warning)) {
            var message = "You will lose your unsaved changes";

            if (event.currentTarget.tagName != "A") {
                return message;
            }

            var conf = confirm(message);

            if (!conf) { //If clicked no prevent click
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
       }
     };

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', showWarning);
    $("a.ajax").click(showWarning); 
});
```

​

Just give your Ajax-links the class ajax like this:

```
<a href="#" class="ajax">Ajax action</a>
```

**Edit: Forgot something, it works now!**

Comment: This almost seemed to work. The issue is when I hit Cancel. When I hit cancel, I still get the other (IE Window) warning with "false" displayed b/w "Are you sure you want to navigage.." and the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a kind of problem releated to a warning message that appear when you enter on a https web sites that have releated media or iframe on an http...